# ¿se puede modificar una plantilla wordpress free para llegar al diseño que uno quiere?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

sinceramente es primera vez que toco wordpress, siempre he programada con javascript y algo (básico) de php. estoy probando con el tema PodCast para lograr un diseño de una barra de navegacición así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero por ejemplo, como haría para agregar el boton que dice "Al aire" ? para eso hay que obligatoriamente instalar un plugin? sinceramente veo mucho mas facil hacer eso con html y css que hacer esto con wordpress pero es lo que me toco. se podría hacer con css y html? no logro donde insertar el código, instale otro plugin para css pero sinceramente no se como entrarle.

Esto es lo único que logrado hacer:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es obligatorio adquirir o buscar una plantilla casi parecida al diseño que uno tiene? imagino que la idea es ahorrar tiempo con eso pero... se puede adaptar cualquier plantilla al diseño que uno quiere o tiene que ser una premium?

agradezco algún consejo y técnicas de alguien con experiencia en wordpress. Gracias de antemno.

Saludos!

Comment: Antes de modificar temas de wordpress te recomiendo crear un tema hijo del mismo, ya que de lo contrario si el tema sufre una actualización, perderás todos los cambios realizados, se oye complicado pero es mas facil de lo que crees, aqui tienes info sobre los temas hijos: [Child Themes Wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)

Comment: Hola @Elboy, consegui poder insertar un boton asi: en el menú, añadi un nuevo elemento (página), le asigné una clase y a esta clase la añadí estilos y funcionó. pregunto: es una buena práctica hacerlo así? ahora estoy viendo como podría modificar la altura de la barra de navegación, modificar el margin o padding del logo para que quede más hacia la izquierda ya que está centrado, se podría hacer de la misma forma que te comento ya que lo veo mucho mas fácil y rápido?

Comment: En teoría si puedes hacerlo, pero en ese caso recomiendo no actualizar el tema cuando salga una actualización, ya que esta sustituye los archivos del mismo, y perderás todo tu trabajo, yo te recomiendo, ya que empiezas con wordpress; que te tomes el trabajo de hacer el tema hijo, y traslades las modificaciones a éste, no es necesario dejar nuevamente el tema como estaba para eso, ya que el tema hijo es el que carga los cambios.

Comment: Ok, gracias, haré un tema hijo y comenzaré a modificar ese. esto tratando de poner un ícono al botón pero no se como? se podría hacer igual agregando una clase y un código css? agregué una etiqueta span en la etiqueta de navegación con una clase y le coloqué de fondo la imágen del ícono pero no me funciona.

Answer (score 3):

Claro que puedes editarla desde el los archivos base de la plantilla, pero necesitas algunas bases de php y funciones nativas de wordpress luego podras customizar todo lo que necesites, ese menu debe estar configurado en el header.php

Para una mejor customizacion puedes crear esta funcion dentro del functions.php

```
function get_custom_menu($menu_name) {
if ( ($locations = get_nav_menu_locations()) && isset( $locations[$menu_name] ) ) {
    $array_menu = wp_get_nav_menu_items($locations[$menu_name]);

    return build_tree($array_menu);
} else {
    return false;
}
}


function build_tree(array &$elements, $parentId = 0) {
$branch = array();

foreach ($elements as $element) {
    if ($element->menu_item_parent == $parentId) {
        $children = build_tree($elements, $element->ID);
        if ($children) {
            $element->children = $children;
        }
        $branch[$element->ID] = $element;
        unset($elements[$element->ID]);
    }
}
return $branch;
}
```

Luego puedes usar la función get_custom_menu('menu_name') y hacer un foreach del array de objetos que retorna y obetener todos los elementos que almacenas en el menu desde wl administrador de wordpress.

```
<ul>
<?php foreach(get_custom_menu('menu_name') as $item) : ?>
<li><a> <?= $item->title ?> </a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
// boton de envivo
</ul>
```

y si quieres agregar el boton de en vivo puedes agregarlo manualmente con html simple como por ejemplo:

```
<li><a href="<?= site_url('/en-vivo'); ?>">En Vivo</a></li>
```

espero te sirva y te de una idea de como customizar tu tema.

Comment: Woao, todo eso para agregar un botón? Es bastante trabajo, es decir que para adaptarlo al diseño que tengo es mucho código el que necesito meter. Esa es la única forma? Imagínate para agregar la barra de búsqueda y lo demás? También tengo que agregar un  slider (vi que hay plugins para eso) pero ninguno es igual al del diseño que me pasaron así que también habría que modificarlo

Comment: Esto puede ser mas simple si exactamente como esta el código actual y ver la manera de hacerlo manualmente. pero yo te di una solución global